# Parse SDK for javascript how to send ping to parse server to verify connection between web client and server

Tags: javascript, parsing, websocket, webclient, parse-javascript-sdk

i iam developing chat app with parse and need to know when the connection is closed on the client side i am trying to send pong to server put  sever didn't recive ping to response with pong any help please `_this2.socket.send({})`

Comment: Hmm strange question from a "I am an expert mobile app developer" as it says in your profile. Last time I checked you should be able to tell if the socket is connected or not, in code, at runtime. Therefore the need to "ping" the server wouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @gforce301 i made it mobile side but my issue . in web side

Comment: It's a websocket yes? Have you bothered to look at the docs on websockets? From my previous comment, which I guess you didn't read, "Last time I checked you should be able to tell if the socket is connected or not, in code, at runtime."

Comment: @gforce301 : if you know how please tell me i google it for many time and can made it if i build node js server use web socket  but with parse i can't if you can help response to me if not leave another one to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by send heartbeat for my server in parse socket every 15 sec this help me in web application

```
_this2.socket.send((0,"heartBeat"));
```